# Floating widget application on LG webOS Smart TV

Tags: webos, smart-tv

I want to write an application in webOS as a widget that will be visible(floating) when other applications are running. Is this possible? I am unable to find any documentation related to this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about it. I'm never see that behaviour in third party apps, only system apps are able to use 'overlay' feature in alerts and notifications dialogues according to WeOs developer site

http://webostv.developer.lge.com/design/webos-tv-system-ui/notifications/